# Can the Laplacian of two graphs have the same eigenvectors but different eigenvalues?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

We know that the Laplacian matrix of a simple graph can be diagonalized as $L = U\Lambda U^T$ where $U$ shows eigenvectors and $\Lambda$ contains the eigenvalues. Can the Laplacian of two different graphs (unweighted and undirected) have the same eigenvectors and their difference is in the eigenvalues? If so, is there any relation between these two graphs?

I think eigenvectors of the Laplacian of all the circulant graphs are the same, but I can't prove it or find any proof for it. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, all circulant matrices have the same eigenvectors. An easy way to see this is to show that they’re all polynomials in a single matrix given by an $n$-cycle.

Comment: In addition to circulant Laplacians, complement Laplacians also have the same eigenvectors but different eigenvalues. Let $L$ be the Laplacian of a graph on $n$ vertices, then the Laplacian for the complement graph is $\Gamma := nI-uu^{\rm T} -L$, where $u$ is the all-ones vector. You can then show that if $(\lambda, v)$ is an eigenpair of $L$ (i.e., $Lv=\lambda v$), then $(n-\lambda, v)$ is an eigenpair or $\Gamma$ (except when $v$ is the all-ones vector, in which case we still have $\Gamma u = 0 u$.)

Comment: Last remark: having same eigenvectors but different eigenvalues is also extensive for block-wise diagonal matrices whose blocks are circulant or complement Laplacians.

Comment: Thanks @Rócherz for your comment, that's interesting.